# 403 Forbidden on Images on my subdomains

Tags: images, 403-forbidden, 1and1

I am pulling my hair out after multiple back and forths with 1and1 support both via email and telephone.

I've setup multiple subdomains via the 1and1 control panel and that looks to work fine. The one in the screenshot below is

http://x3.keefermadness.com

Everything loads properly except images. Inspecting them, they're giving a 403 Forbidden. I've tried changing the permissions on individual files and the directories in that structure to no avail.

1and1 keeps blaming it on my image references, but they work fine locally via MAMP with no changes to anything.

Any ideas? 1and1 has been completely worthless, and I'm very close to just moving to another web host.

I've tried other web content, including a clean wordpress install. No images ever load. Everything else - html, JS, CSS, loads fine.

[image: 403 forbidden]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just looked at your page source, and (example) image: http://x3.keefermadness.com/lib/img/home/home-about.jpg loads perfectly fine by visiting that URL. Do you have a setting enabled for "disallow hotlinking" of images somewhere? It is possible that that could be causing the problem.

Comment: Crap! Good call.
In the root of the domain, I had these rules:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?keefermadness.com [NC]
# RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ - [NC,F,L]

Answer (score 0):

We removed the last line on the *.htaccess* file

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?zzz\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?zzz\.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g|js|css|png)$ - [F,NC,L]
```

which was returning the forbidden action for images and CSS

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?zzz\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?zzz\.co.uk [NC]
```

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_f